# How to make a collection of fixed postion div elements scrollable as a whole if it exceeds the screen

Tags: html

I am working on creating a metadata on scanned documents. The output it generates is an html file which retains the position of text as in the image. The structure of output html generated is as given below.

```html
    <page num="1" src="document_name">
        <Blocks>
            <line>
            <div coordinates="1777,2546,52,40" index="0" style="position:fixed;left:53.86%;top:33%;height:1.17%;width:1.51%;">content_at_that_position</div>
            </line>
        </Blocks>
    </page>
    <!-- There will be n number of line elements -->
```

So basically a given scanned pdf will generate output html file with text data retaining its position. The issue I am facing is that the html generated is not scrollable. The output can only be visualized in the existing window size only.

How Can I make this whole collection of divs scrollable?

I tried changing the position from fixed to relative and absolute. But this creates an overlapping noisy output.

For eg: Condsider this as the input image.
[image: input image]

With `position:fixed`
[image: with position fixed]
As you can see, the scroll is not available.

With `position:absolute`
[image: with position Absolute]
The scroll option is available, But output is overlapping and noisy.

I am not much familiar with HTML. Please help me to correct this minor issue.
Is there any way we can achieve this
[Attaching a sample html file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KiwX1yTutiXZK6l9qvjrPb3aYD5k4L-J)

Comment: why not simply create a wrapper element (which has `position: fixed; height: 100vh; overflow: auto`) and placing the images as it's naturally-document-following content?

Comment: use `overflow: auto`

Comment: I created a wrapper, but the wrapper becomes scrollable, but the sub divs are still fixed.

Answer (score 1):

So while I am not exactly sure of what you are after, I think this is what you are asking for (see below for code). I set the overflow for the blocks element to "overflow" and white-space to "nowrap". This will cause the content to overflow the screen and allow for scrolling. I did this based off the html document you provided and I removed the CSS that was present.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <page num="1" src="img/Document2 (1/Document2 (1-0.jpg">
    <blocks style="overflow: scroll;white-space: nowrap;">
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1777,2546,52,40" index="0" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:53.862465919418355%; *//*! top:100.03921568627452%; *//*! height:1.1764705882352942%; *//*! width:1.5146925174189638%; */" type="line">of</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="172,238,310,42" index="1" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:5.2408361102696155%; *//*! top:9.529411764705882%; *//*! height:1.2549019607843137%; *//*! width:9.330505907300818%; */" type="line">Â© 2016, DESIDOC</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1605,1166,551,45" index="2" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:48.65192365949712%; *//*! top:45.92156862745098%; *//*! height:1.3725490196078431%; *//*! width:16.631323841260222%; */" type="line">prob_1ems_ 9f frequent Po_se change,</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1777,2546,52,40" index="0" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:53.862465919418355%; *//*! top:100.03921568627452%; *//*! height:1.1764705882352942%; *//*! width:1.5146925174189638%; */" type="line">of</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="172,238,310,42" index="1" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:5.2408361102696155%; *//*! top:9.529411764705882%; *//*! height:1.2549019607843137%; *//*! width:9.330505907300818%; */" type="line">Â© 2016, DESIDOC</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1605,1166,551,45" index="2" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:48.65192365949712%; *//*! top:45.92156862745098%; *//*! height:1.3725490196078431%; *//*! width:16.631323841260222%; */" type="line">prob_1ems_ 9f frequent Po_se change,</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1777,2546,52,40" index="0" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:53.862465919418355%; *//*! top:100.03921568627452%; *//*! height:1.1764705882352942%; *//*! width:1.5146925174189638%; */" type="line">of</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="172,238,310,42" index="1" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:5.2408361102696155%; *//*! top:9.529411764705882%; *//*! height:1.2549019607843137%; *//*! width:9.330505907300818%; */" type="line">Â© 2016, DESIDOC</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1605,1166,551,45" index="2" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:48.65192365949712%; *//*! top:45.92156862745098%; *//*! height:1.3725490196078431%; *//*! width:16.631323841260222%; */" type="line">prob_1ems_ 9f frequent Po_se change,</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1777,2546,52,40" index="0" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:53.862465919418355%; *//*! top:100.03921568627452%; *//*! height:1.1764705882352942%; *//*! width:1.5146925174189638%; */" type="line">of</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="172,238,310,42" index="1" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:5.2408361102696155%; *//*! top:9.529411764705882%; *//*! height:1.2549019607843137%; *//*! width:9.330505907300818%; */" type="line">Â© 2016, DESIDOC</div>
      </line>
      <line style="display: inline-block;">
        <div coordinates="1605,1166,551,45" index="2" style="/*! position:fixed; *//*! left:48.65192365949712%; *//*! top:45.92156862745098%; *//*! height:1.3725490196078431%; *//*! width:16.631323841260222%; */" type="line">prob_1ems_ 9f frequent Po_se change,</div>
      </line>
    </blocks>
  </page>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That CSS cannot be removed. The position of each line is a must for my output. When I create a wrapper without removing css, the wrapper is able to scroll, but all the sub divs are still fixed.

Comment: If this is the case then I am 100% sure what you are asking can not be done. The CSS I commented out gives your content a fixed position. This mean it will always be in that spot. Please see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.